# Adding link to a javascript element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show a table in a modal window. This table has 3 columns and I want to assign a link to the first column item for each row. Here is my code

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
var id = <?php echo json_encode($id); ?>; // PHP değişkenini JavaScript'e aktar
var modal = document.getElementById("modalTablo"); // Modal değişkenini tanımla
var closeButton = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-tablo-close")[0];

if (id) { // Eğer ID boş değilse
    fetch('ajax_table_data_fetch.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: 'id=' + id
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        var table = document.getElementById("modalTabloTable");
        table.innerHTML = ""; // Tabloyu temizle
        if (data.length > 0) {
            var thead = table.createTHead();
            var row = thead.insertRow();
            Object.keys(data[0]).forEach(function(key) {
                var th = document.createElement("th");
                th.innerText = key;
                row.appendChild(th);
            });

            data.forEach(function(item) {
                var row = table.insertRow();
                Object.values(item).forEach(function(value) {
                    var cell = row.insertCell();
                    cell.innerText = value;
                });
            });
        }
  
        modal.style.display = "block";
    })
```

I need help adding a link to the first column of each row. Thanks

Comment: You'll have to modify what happens in that `Object.values(item).forEach` loop then. The callback function takes the index as second parameter, that helps you identify the first cell. And then you simply need to make an assignment to `cell.innerHTML` instead, with your desired HTML content for the cell.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Remove the PHP and the AJAX, make a mock object and post that and the function that formats it. The rest of your code is irrelevant

Comment: in the innermost `forEach`, do `function(value, i) { const cell = /*...*/; if (i == 0) cell.onclick = yourHandler }`? Or wrap the text you put in the cell in an `a` element

Comment: @DustInComp Delegation from the tbody is much cleaner

Comment: `Object.values(item).forEach((value,i) => { var cell = row.insertCell(); cell.innerHTML = (i === 0) ? \`<a href="somewhere?id=${encodeURIComponent(value)}">${value}</a>\` : value ; });` but pay attention to XSS here

Comment: @mplungjan Setting `innerHTML` is a [potential security risk](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#replacing_the_contents_of_an_element). `value`s may be user-supplied

Comment: Hence the "Pay attention to XSS"

Answer (score 0):

You can test if you are creating the first cell and then insert an anchor.

```js
var table = document.getElementById("modalTabloTable");
var thead = table.tHead;
var tbody = table.tBodies[0];

while (thead.rows.length > 0) {
  thead.deleteRow(0);
}
while (tbody.rows.length > 0) {
  tbody.deleteRow(0);
}

const data = [{
    id: 0,
    title: "Test 1"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Test 2"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Test 3"
  }
];

let theadrow = thead.insertRow();

Object.keys(data[0]).forEach(function(key) {
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerText = key;
  theadrow.appendChild(th);
});

data.forEach(function(item) {
  let row = tbody.insertRow();
  Object.keys(item).forEach((key, i) => {
    let cell = row.insertCell();
    if (i == 0) {
      let anchor = document.createElement('A');
      anchor.href = `#${item[key]}`;
      anchor.innerText = item[key];
      cell.appendChild(anchor);
    } else {
      cell.innerText = item[key];
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<table id="modalTabloTable">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```